# How to avoid org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: java, swt, listener

I have a listener to an SWT button which starts like this:

```
button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        String nextValue = text1.getText();
        ...
```

I need the current value of the Text field called text1 in the UI, but the last line getText() fails with

`org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access`

I know about syncExec/asyncExec (my code has several) but other threads here at StackOverflow suggest you only need to use it when you want to update a field in the UI.  What is the correct way to read a UI field inside a listener?

Comment: All interactions with SWT UI objects must run on the UI thread, not just updating. Why are you using a `Runnable` here?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some code fragments that demonstrate how to run code synchronously & asynchronously (copied from [Lars Vogel's](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) VERY useful site).

```
// Update the user interface asynchronously
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    // ... do any work that updates the screen ...
   }
});

// Update the user interface synchronously

Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    // do any work that updates the screen ...
    // remember to check if the widget
    // still exists
    // might happen if the part was closed
   }
});
```

Comment: Er....  With respect, I told you I knew about asyncExec, and I have some in my code, so I know how to write them.  It cannot be the way to _read_ fields from my own UI.

Comment: @casgage SWT is single-threaded. `(a)syncExec` is *the only way* to access widgets from a non-UI thread - regardless if the code 'reads' or 'writes' widget properties. If other SO threads claim it is only needed to update widgets they are wrong. Here is some more on the [SWT threading model](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fswt_threading.htm).

Comment: @david Just wanted to say (even if this question is kind of old) that this answer is totally valid because it helped me out to solve this very same issue.